# Lost iPhone contacts names, need to sync them to computer

Tags: itunes, iphone

When I synced on iTunes all my contacts were lost. Favorites became just numbers with no names. What happened? If any way to transfer and back up my iPhone contacts to a computer without iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to officially sync/read any iOS device is through iTunes, with a version up to date with the iOS software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [iCloud](https://www.icloud.com/), which can be set up in the settings app on your iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options (last one requires iTunes, though)

- Setup iCloud sync standalone -- this stores your contact information in "the cloud" and across multiple iOS devices.
- Setup iCloud sync with Outlook or Windows Live Mail -- you must install the [iCloud Control Panel](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1455), but after that, you can sync your contacts with either Outlook or Windows Live Mail.
- Setup standard iTunes sync to Outlook/Google Contacts/Windows Contacts/Yahoo Address Book -- you get this by visiting the "Info" tab when selecting your iPhone in iTunes.

Comment: Where did you find the information that iCloud would sync with Windows Live Mail? The link only says that Outlook is needed.